# Changing href attribute to generated string from API with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attributes, href

I want to change the `href` attritube of link on this part of the code

```
<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" class="author" target="_BLANK"></a>
```

I'm using this code to change the href attribute

```
$('a').attr('href', function() {
return this.href + update.response;
});
```

I tried to make a variable in this function

```
function update(response) {

  $('#response').html(JSON.stringify(response.quoteText));
 var okay = $('.author').html(JSON.stringify(response.quoteAuthor));

}
```

But I can't seem to access it from outside scope.

Basically I want to link to Wikipedia author page by adding the `$('.author')` name at the end of link. 
Added the `update.response` to the end of link but I get **undefined**

[CodePen Link](http://codepen.io/Agonn/pen/vXdWEQ)

Comment: Just a small note:  creating a codePen was very useful.  But even better is using Stack Overflows snippets.  It's just as easy as codePen, if not easier.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just update the href at the point you get your response.

eg.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rrJYbJ

```
var a = $('a'),
   wiki = a.attr('href');

function update(response) {
  $('#response').html(JSON.stringify(response.quoteText));
  $('.author').html(JSON.stringify(response.quoteAuthor));
  a.attr('href',wiki + response.quoteAuthor);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is `response` coming from?

did you declare it as a global variable? eg `var response;`

if so then just place this code:

```
$('a').attr('href', function() {
   return this.href + response; // you dont need update.response just response
});
```

**after** wherever you're calling `update();`

Comment: response is a JSON, assigning that to a href doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

There's some erros in your code:

- Where response came from?
- You should update link href after receive data from api.

You can try to alter your code like this:

```
<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" data-base-href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" class="author" target="_BLANK"></a>
```

And js:

```
function update(response) {

  $('#response').html(JSON.stringify(response.quoteText));
  $('.author').html(JSON.stringify(response.quoteAuthor));

  $('a').each( function () {
    var newHref = $(this).data('data-base-href')+response.quoteAuthor;
    $(this).attr('href',newHref );
  });
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, every time you request a quote, the Author's are going to append to the url,.. I made that mistake too, I just captured the wiki href outside of the update function.

Comment: Just set the original href in a data-value. I've updated the answer.